# ImportError: Could not import settings 'testapp.settings.local'

Tags: python, django

I am installed django in my ubuntu server , 
I try to run the  following command :

./manage.py syncdb --noinput

or

```
/manage.py runserver --settings=testapp.settings.local
```

or any command through manage.py , 
I get the  following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cchq/.virtualenvs/commcare-hq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cchq/.virtualenvs/commcare-hq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/cchq/.virtualenvs/commcare-hq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/cchq/.virtualenvs/commcare-hq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/cchq/.virtualenvs/commcare-hq/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'testapp.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named testapp.settings.local
```

Below is my manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

How can I solve this problem ? 
Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `testapp/settings` directory which will contain at least two files: the `local.py` with your settings and `__init__.py`.

And don't forget to remove the `testapp/settings.py` if it exist (it's content should be moved to the `testapp/settings` dir).